# Sorting doesnt work for resources in resourceTimeGridPlugin fullcalender

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Resources list is sorted when provided to full calender component but it gets randomly sorted automatically.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - i.e. enough code and data to enable us to understand and reproduce your issue. Otherwise, there is unlikely to be much we can do to help you.

Comment: P.S. This demo demonstrates that resources are loaded in the order provided in the JSON feed (you can use the Network tool in the browser to show what's returned by the server, to prove it): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/VwexwRN . So if you have a different case, I'd say it's probably more likely that your server is doing something wrong than fullCalendar. But you need to provide some practical information before we can help you to solve anything specific in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be you are using more or less random ids for your resources? It seems that by default resources are being sorted by id. Just stumbled across the same issue.

Also you can change the ordering: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resourceOrder

Comment: I have the ids sortred by the index. I think character ids might work

Answer (score 1):

The calendar seems to have a default sorting, if you are using React (`"@fullcalendar/react"`) you just need to pass the `resourceOrder="any key that is not in your object"` prop.

It helped in my case.

```
resources = [{id: "string", title:"string", children:[{id: "string", title:"string"}]},...]
```